# Where is model directory in pocketsphinx

Tags: python, windows, pocketsphinx

I'm trying to make a simple speech recognition program in Python using Sphinx. I installed it using pip in CMD, then I installed PocketSphinx in the same way. The tutorial I'm following says I need to include the model directories for PocketSphinx, but I don't know where the directory is. How do I find it, and am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It is in pocketsphinx sources `models` folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [pocketsphinx-python](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-python) installed via `pip`, and following some example code similar to that provided by the package's github page, you may find there are a few code changes needed.

Here's what's [currently in the README](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-python/blob/dfca2739c7a32dd474c425dad1cf87c1d6e1a316/readme.md) (as of March 11, 2018):

```
from pocketsphinx.pocketsphinx import *
from sphinxbase.sphinxbase import *

MODELDIR = "pocketsphinx/model"
DATADIR = "pocketsphinx/test/data"

# Create a decoder with certain model
config = Decoder.default_config()
config.set_string('-hmm', path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/en-us'))
config.set_string('-lm', path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/en-us.lm.bin'))
config.set_string('-dict', path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict'))
```

[This not-yet-accepted pull request](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-python/pull/33) describes some changes which may help for those of us using `pip` and working on our python code outside the downloaded module's directory (at least in a *nix/Mac environment, I haven't tested on Windows). Here's a diff snippet; **the key idea** is to use `path.dirname(pocketsphinx.__file__)` to get the base directory in which to look for the model directory:

```
-MODELDIR = "pocketsphinx/model"
-DATADIR = "pocketsphinx/test/data"
+import pocketsphinx;
+POCKETSPHINXDIR = path.dirname(pocketsphinx.__file__)
+MODELDIR = path.join(POCKETSPHINXDIR, "model")
+DATADIR = path.join(POCKETSPHINXDIR, "data")
```

(Small note: I took liberty to fix a small typo in the spelling of `POCKETSPHINXDIR`, so this code isn't *exactly* the same as the pull request)

Answer (score 0):

Go the location where your python is installed look for the following location inside that (this location is according to windows installation)

Lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\pocketsphinx-data

default model is en-US however there are few other language models that one can download from here

https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/

Answer (score 0):

It may be late to answer now, but for newcomers, Python module has some convenience methods:

```
from pocketsphinx import get_model_path, get_data_path
print(get_model_path())
print(get_data_path())
```